# Any way to Keep LiveStream active on Youtube Livestream?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'd like to livestreaming my lectures to Youtube with youtube-livestreaming-api.

I create new live events when the lectures start and I transit my LiveEvent to completion when the lectures end.

The problem is break-time. when break-time short, I don't need to change or insert LiveStream because the Live Stream is still active even though LiveEvents stop. The problem is when the break-time  long, the Live Stream turns to inactive. so I can't transition to testing and live. Is there any way to keep LiveStream active?

Any Suggestion? or Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `LiveBroadcasts:transition` and should confirm that the value of the [`status.streamStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#properties) property for the stream bound to your broadcast is `active`

A liveStream resource contains information about the video stream that you are transmitting to YouTube. The stream provides the content that will be broadcast to YouTube users.

**HTTP request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition
```

Note: This request requires authorization with at least one of the following [scopes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication).

The parameter `broadcastStatus` identifiees the state of which the broadcast is changing. Note that to transition a broadcast to either the testing or live state. `live` is visible to its audience. YouTube transmits video to the broadcast's monitor stream and its broadcast stream.

Comment: thanks d.datul1990.
my question is how to keep LiveStream active.
Is it possible 'status.streamStatus' active unrelated with broadcast status?

Comment: This answer helps a lot.